# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar en una consola la base de datos que he creado en C#?

Tags: c#, base-de-datos

Buenos días! Estoy conectando la base de datos donde he creado una tabla con el visual Studio 2017. Ya he usado un método para conectarme a la base de datos y cuando le doy a "play" se me muestra una consola pero sin mostrarme la tabla que cree en la base datos.¿Podríais ayudarme porfa?

Aquí me conecto con mi base de datos:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConexionTablas2
{
    public class SQLServerDatabaseHelper
    {
        public static SqlConnection Getconnection()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server = SERVIDOR-SQL.XXXXX.local; Initial Catalog = XXXXX_DEV; Persist Security Info = False; User ID = USERXXXXX; Password = XXXXXHR-XXXXX@02; MultipleActiveResultSets = False; Encrypt = True; TrustServerCertificate = False; Connection Timeout = 30;");
            conn.Open();
            return conn;
        }

        public static void CloseConnection(DbConnection conn)
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Y aquí quiero llamar la base de datos (osea la conexion) para que se me muestre en la consola la tabla creada:

```
 using ConexionTablas2;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConexionTablas2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             Console.WriteLine();
             Console.ReadLine();
          } 
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano!!! ;) :-*

Comment: Hola @SilviaGarcia, lo primero, no es recomendable que pongas la cadena de conexión con los datos a la vista, quítalos en el código para que nadie pueda hacer nada no deseado. Segundo, a que te refieres con que te muestre la tabla que has creado???

Comment: Si, elimina la cadena de conexion del texto o pon datos no reales, y si tienes posibilidad de hablar con el administrador de base da datos no estaria mal que cambiasen la contraseña y el usuario. poner esos datos es muy peligroso para la seguridad de tu empresa.

Comment: Gracias @PabloSimonDiEstefano, como puedo editar la pregunta para poder quitar la conexion?

Comment: justo debajo de tu pregunta, bajo las etiquetas, te saldrá "editar", ahí tienes que darle

Comment: Gracias por la recomendacion de la conexion! ;) Lo que quiero decir en cuanto a mi pregunta es que yo en el MySql Server he creado dos columnas con usuarios y grupos con sus respectivos datos. Cuando conecto con esta base de datos quiero que se me muestre en la consola estas dos columnas que he creado como si fuese una tabla.

Comment: Nada de todo lo que escribiste en tu codigo hace eso. Vamos por el principio, cuando decis mostrar por consola, que es lo que queres decir? pon un ejemplo claro. Ademas, en ningun lado estas haciendo un select (si quisieras mostrar los datos), y tu metodo main no hace absolutamente nada. Queres que solucionemos el problema por vos o te equivocaste de codigo?

Comment: Pues es verdad, en tu código nunca te va a mostrar nada porque no haz seleccionado nada, además sin la estructura de tu base de datos difícil que te ayudemos. Lo que quieres ver es lo mismo que harías en una query del management?? Me refiero a un "select * from tu_tabla" pero en una app c#? de ser así no tiene mucho sentido, lo que deberías hacer es pasar esos datos a un DataTable, en consola no te serviría de mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Usa esto

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Tu conexión"))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nombre FROM mitabla", con))
                        {
                            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                if (reader.HasRows)
                                {
                                    while (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        valor = Convert.ToString(reader["Nombre"]);
                                        Console.Write(valor);

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Console.Read();
```